# dictionary.copy() seems to reference to the same memory location

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-manipulation

I was trying to write a code that modifies a dictionary of dictionaries in python so if the inner dictionary value is a NaN *obtained from a pandas.DataFrame* then remove the key of the inner dictionary but for a reason, the code keeps showing this error

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

even though I did copy the dictionary to another variable before iterating to avoid any complications as seen in my following code

```
def xls_to_dict_of_dict(filename):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df.fillna("NotaNumber", inplace=True)
    dict_of_dicts = {}
    try:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            dict_of_dicts[row[1]] = {}
            for i in range(2, len(row)):
                dict_of_dicts[row[1]][row[i]] = df.iloc[index + 1][i]
    except:
        pass
    return dict_of_dicts


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_of_dicts = xls_to_dict_of_dict('Excel.xlsx')

    dict_of_dictsTemp = dict_of_dicts.copy()
    for k, v in dict_of_dictsTemp.items():
        for k2, v2 in v.items():
            if v2 == "NotaNumber":
                dict_of_dicts[k].pop(k2)
    for k, v in dict_of_dicts.items():
        for k2, v2 in v.items():
            print(k2, v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

the statement `dict_of_dicts[k].pop(k2)` is modifying the sub dictionary, it is the same dictionary as `v` in your loop:

```
dict_of_dictsTemp = dict_of_dicts.copy()
for k, v in dict_of_dictsTemp.items():
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        assert v is dict_of_dicts[k]
```

you don't actually need to create a copy of the top level dictionary since you don't modify that one, just make a copy of the `items` for the sub dictionaries

```
for k, v in dict_of_dicts.items():
    for k2, v2 in list(v.items()): # here using list to keep all keys 
        if v2 == "NotaNumber":
            v.pop(k2)
```